# Azure Fluent Api for AzureADB2C Creation

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-fluent-api

I am looking for Azure Fluent API tutorial for Azure ADB2C Management. I want to create Azure ADB2C and Applications under Azure ADB2C using Microsoft.Azure.Management.ResourceManager.Fluent;

Is there any tutorial or code for this?

Thanks in advance,
Subbiah K

Comment: Do you want to create Azure ADB2C tenant programmatically?

Comment: Yes, I am looking for the same exaactly